# Make a website mobile ready

Tags: mobile

I have a website and i want this to be mobile ready. I found Kurogo very helpful for static website. But this is not useful when i have a website where there are many forms and all. which is the best way to convert a website mobile ready where it has many forms, add, edit , update forms and all. I use php/mysql for my application.

Answer (score 1):

you can always try to use [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or [zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and then load the css using a media query